# Unable to run .NET Windows service with Entity Framework 6

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

**Problem**

I am getting an InvalidOperationException when trying to use Entity Framework in my Windows service application. (Edit: Specficially *No connection string named 'MyProjectEntities' could be found in the application config file.*)

**Background**

I have a solution which scrapes an RSS feed on an interval and stores the data in a local SQL Server database. I'm using Entity Framework 6 and building this as a Windows service.

The application works from my TestConsole project just fine. However, when I try to run it as a Windows service, the application crashes on the first attempted interaction with the database.

My application is structured as:

- MyProject.Core (EF model plus rest of my logic)
- MyProject.TestConsole (working console version)
- MyProject.Service (non-working Windows service)

The specific location of my EF model is in /Core/Data/MyProjectDB.emdx

**Error**

The error I'm getting per the Windows event log is

```
Application: MyProject.Service.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
Stack:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(System.Type)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__MyCompany, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1[[System.__MyCompany, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[[System.__MyCompany, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[[System.__MyCompany, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__MyCompany, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
```

This is the offending code

```
Private Shared Function GetRSSLinks() As String()
    Dim efm As New MyProjectEntities
    Dim links As String() = (From l In efm.ScrapeLists Select l.RSSLink).ToArray
    Return links
End Function
```

I have an App.config set up in my Service project and the EF connection is copied over from the working TestConsole project:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.MyProjectDB.csdl|res://*/Data.MyProjectDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.MyProjectDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyProject;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

In the folder where I've installed the Windows service, I have the following files

- MyProject.Service.exe
- MyProject.Core.dll
- EntityFramework.dll
- EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

I also installed EF via NuGet to the Service project. What am I missing?

**Edit - Updated error**

I wrapped the code in a Try/Catch to get the specific error message and it says:

```
No connection string named 'MyProjectEntities' could be found in the application config file.
```

However I did make an entry for this connection in my App.config

Comment: You're using integrated security to access the database. What account is your service running under? Does it have access to the database?

Comment: I made an edit to show an additional error. Specifically that the connection string cannot be found. To answer your question, it's running as Network Service and that account as a SQL Server login

Answer (score 3):

And now I feel dumb after scratching my head over this for a while. For future reference you have to copy your config file over to the directory of your Windows service application.

In my case, this file was MyProject.Service.exe.config

Comment: Tip: Use wrappers for methods that read configuration data and have them throw an exception when the key isn't found. It's a lot easier to track down `Configuration file does not contain connection string "Mispelled"`.